# Batch files update even though content not saved/updated

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

Let's say I have a batch file on Windows 10 with the following content:

```
:loop
echo start
timeout /t 100 /nobreak
goto :loop
```

If I run the batch file from the command line, as expected it echoes `start` every 100 seconds.

If however I edit the batch file *but don't save it* the timer updates. So I could edit it down to 10 seconds and `start` would print every 10 seconds.

This makes no sense to me on two levels:

- surely the loop is loaded into memory and then just run? Even if I saved the change to the file, the script should be executed as first loaded, not checking back to the content of the batch file every time?
- how does the script know the edits I have made to the file if they have not been saved and finalised? I am using Sublime Text and not altering the file in any way.

Comment: `surely the loop is loaded into memory and then just run? ` - Nope. The parser loads each (logical) line from the file, executes it before loading the next line *from the file*.

Comment: It is not quite clear, what are you trying to achieve - I ran your file and it is echoing out start, then waits 100s and repeats the cycle infinitely. 
Maybe you post the edits, you were talking about?

Comment: I don't know Sublime Text, but found a `save_on_focus_lost` setting in the [documentation](https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/settings.html#visual-settings), which would answer your second question.

Comment: I think I understand his issue - sublime text makes it able to auto run the code right after you typed something and saved it, the compiler restarts program/ webapp automatically. Probably with batch files that is not possible?

Comment: @Stephan it seems you're right. I have `save_on_focus_lost` activated. I guess I never noticed it because other languages load the whole file at once rather than line by line.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the command prompt rereads the batch file rather than saving it to memory. So every time you jump to a new label (in this instance is :loop), it rereads the contents beneath it. Same applies if it's going to a new label. Batch will reread all the contents from the label. Also, another possibility is that you have auto save on.

Comment: That would make sense if I'm saving the file but I'm not. And no autosave is on. Sublime Text still shows the file as having unsaved changes.